# Collapse bootstrap скрывать на мобильных

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap4

Сейчас блок всегда открыт. Задача - скрывать toggle-элемент на мобильных устройствах.

```
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
<div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос - это можно решить, только js `if ($(window).width() > 760)`, насильно коллапсируя элемент (или сажая в aria-expanded="false" и добавляя/удаляя класс show). Как это реализовать рационально (чтобы элемент сразу находился в нужном состоянии, а не сначала появлялся, а потом вдруг раскрывался/скрывался?)

Comment: какой-нибудь `d-none d-md-block`

Comment: Особенность в том, что это не работает в связке с collapse() - он сам управляет сурытием/отображением элемента, и при таком решении элемент всегда будет скрыт (ибо у кнопки висит изначально aria-expanded="true", а блок не отображен, и наоборот, при нажатии aria-expanded="false" теперь уже это дополнительно начинает скрывать блок)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте медиа-запросы css

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #collapseExample {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
<div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В маленьком окне выполненный код не покажет блок с текстом, а если развернуть на всю страницу то он становится видимым

Comment: Особенность в том, что это не работает в связке с collapse() - он сам управляет сурытием/отображением элемента, и при таком решении элемент всегда будет скрыт (ибо у кнопки висит изначально aria-expanded="true", а блок не отображен, и наоборот, при нажатии aria-expanded="false" теперь уже это дополнительно начинает скрывать блок)